# Button-Event do not Work in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem:

I have a button like: `<button id="button_show_countries" >Start</button>`
in the index.html
and a click event in the view.js:

```
        $("button#button_show_countries").click(function() {
            debug('View Click Event triggered: notice the Controller that the user wants to see the Interests data');
            Controller().countrieslandscapeasked();
        });
```

This wokrs very well. Now I create with the view a button. This button I add to index.html. The button looks like:

```
   <button class="insertButton" type="button" id="insert_button_0">insert here</button>
```

and in the view is also an eventlistener for this:

```
$("#insert_button_0").click(function() {
            debug('Data should be add at Position 0');

        });
```

But when I click on the button the event is not "fired". What is wrong with my code? :/ 
The button work, if I add him at the beginning like the show countries button. 
Is it problematic that I add the button dynamically at runtime?

Thanks for help.

Comment: The `click()` binds event on the elements which are present in the DOM. Use event delegation `$(document).on('click', '#insert_button_0', function() {`. Instead of using `document` as target, use static parent.

Comment: sorry, I do not really know what you mean. Where I should add this line? I work, with a MVC, so I can not call the method directly in the index.html or?

Comment: First of all, read the answers on the above link, and you'll understand. You need to use the `$(document).on('click', '#insert_button_0', function() {` in place of `$("#insert_button_0").click(function() {`.

Comment: sorry I get it. I must add this line in the view... thanks a lot

Comment: sorry, but I had another question which is I thin neraly the same. I had add also dynamically an selector. Now I would get when I press on the button insert_button_0 the selected element. I tryed it with: var selected = $("select#not_added").find('option:selected'); But it does not work, i alway get that selected is undifined